# asp.net global resources error 'The resource object with key '' was not found'

Tags: asp.net, resx, multilingual

I'm using asp.net global resource to try and implement a two language website, I added a simple resource in the global resource file called **en-Us.resx** that contains:

```
Password | Text
Email | Text
```

then implemented it to a textbox within the default page:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="loginEmail" Text="<%$ Resources:en-US, Email %>" 
                            ></asp:TextBox>
```

but when ever I run the page on **localhost** I get this error:

> The resource object with key '' was not found

I am using asp.net 4.0, what is the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The format of resource files are ResourceName.culture.resx

Create a resource file in the App_GlobalResources folder called 
Main.resx.  This is for the default culture ( ie Invariant )

Then create a resource file Main.en-US.resx

This is where all the resources for en-US culture will live, and so on.

```
Main.resx  
Main.en.resx  
Main.en-US-resx  
Main.en-AU.resx  
Main.fr.resx  
Main.fr-FR.resx
```

etc.

To access this from the webpage use the syntax

```
<%$ Resources:Main, Email %>
```

Don't worry around the culture, the system will work it out.  It will exact match first ( en-US ), then work up to that's cultures parent ( en ), parent's parent ( Invariant ).

Change the name of "Main" to suit your needs

Comment: If I have two different keys i.e Email and Message, but at end of the page I have to shown Email Message can I able to merge two existing keys or I need to create new key as Email Message

Comment: If you have to show both, the just use 2 <%$  %>, one for each key

Answer (score -1):

1. Change your file name to en-US.aspx.resx and try again.  See [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1243309.aspx/1) helps.
2. Try changing the build actions and see what happens. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744695/the-resource-object-with-key-key-was-not-found-auto-deployed-asp-net-mvc3-a)

Comment: tried changing the name, still throws the same error. i think this is only for local resources.

Comment: Check this one out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744695/the-resource-object-with-key-key-was-not-found-auto-deployed-asp-net-mvc3-a