# How to make multilinguage link text li menu and dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I cannot post my code but I want to know how I can write in resource file and other the link text in masterpage like and dropdownlist multilinguage in asp.net c# website.i need to use global app.global resources due to my desire to localize it in many languages to handle the files.i will be happy if you show me in asp.net website only i do not have much knowledge in mvc and web application and moreover what i started to do is in asp.net website.

```
                             <li><a href="Buy.aspx">Buy</a></li>
                <li><a href="Rent.aspx">Rent</a></li>
                <li><a href="Estimate.aspx">Estimate</a></li>
                <% if (Session["user"] == null)
                    { %>
                <li><a href="login.aspx">Sell</a></li>
               <% }
                   else
                   { %>
                <li><a href="Sell.aspx">Sell</a></li>  
               <%} %>          

    <asp:ListItem>Select the Category</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Villa</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Apartment and Condos</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Farm</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Office</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Store</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Storey House</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Plot</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Shop</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Other commercial</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add resource files for the different languages, e.g. `LocalizedText.resx` (fallback language), `LocalizedText.fr.resx` (french), `LocalizedText.de.resx` (german), etc.
Add keys and values for the texts to be translated to these resource files, e.g. `Villa`, `ApartmentAndCondos`.

Then ASP.net will resolve the correct language version of the resource file to be used based on the language sent by the browser.

```
<asp:ListItem><%$ Resources:LocalizedText, Villa %></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem><%$ Resources:LocalizedText, ApartmentAndCondos %></asp:ListItem>
```

You can use the `<%$ Resources:{FileName}, {ResourceKey} %>` command anywhere to return translations. E.g. in a link:

```
<a href="login.aspx"><%$ Resources:Resources:LocalizedText, Sell %></a>
```

See [Walkthrough: Using Resources for Localization with ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx).

Comment: Great thanks but i would like you show me the globalization cause i like to work it with that way and also i appreciate also show me the link texts how i deal with them.

Comment: See [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) on how to pass the language from the Browser to ASP.net so it will be used to resolve resource files and date/number formats etc.

Comment: i tried the <a href="login.aspx"><%$ Resources:Resources:LocalizedText, Sell %></a> and gave me error message Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Literal expressions like '<%$ Resources:Resources:LocalizedText, Sell %>' are not allowed. Use <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resources:LocalizedText, Sell%>" /> instead.even after using recommended it gave me also an error.

Comment: after i tried again it gave me a message The resource object with key 'sell' was not found

Comment: You added the string resource with the key "Sell" to the .resx file?

Comment: i tried like that uut still give me the same message The resource object with key 'sell' was not found

Comment: Maybe its a Problem with the name of the .resx file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574760/1450855

Comment: the resource file is correct sorry if i bother you MasterPage.master.resx and MasterPage.master.fr.resx

Comment: Then you have to call this file : `'<%$ Resources:MasterPage.master, Sell %>`

Comment: it worked when i did it like the page you redirected me thank you i did it <%$ Resources:MasterPage.master, sell%> Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help :)